# Angular 6 - employee: Observable<Employee[]>; bad response in console

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

my code:

```
import { Employee } from './../employee';
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { EmployeeService } from '../employee.service';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import {Observable} from "rxjs";
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-employee-details',
  templateUrl: './employee-details.component.html'

})
export class EmployeeDetailsComponent implements OnInit {
  employee: Observable<Employee[]>;
  constructor(private employeeService: EmployeeService,
              private router: Router,
              private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  private id: number;
  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.id = +params['id'];
      console.log(this.id);
    }); // get id and convert to number
    this.loadData(this.id); // return number from url
    }

  loadData(id: number) {
    this.employee = this.employeeService.getEmployee(this.id).pipe(map(employees => employees.data));
    console.log(this.employee);
  }
}
```

and template:

```
<div *ngIf="employee">
  <div>
    <label>Name: </label> {{employee?.name}}
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>Last Name: </label> {{employee?.lastname}}
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>E-mail: </label> {{employee?.email}}
  </div>
 <hr/>
</div>
```

console.log(this.employee);

back to console:

> Observable {_isScalar: false, source: Observable, operator:
>   MapOperator}_isScalar: falsesource: Observable_isScalar: falsesource:
>   Observable {_isScalar: false, source: Observable, operator:
>   FilterOperator}operator: MapOperator {thisArg: undefined, project:
>   ƒ}**proto**: Objectoperator: MapOperator {thisArg: undefined, project:
>   ƒ}**proto**: Object

why? how fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First and foremost, the `loadData()` should be nested within the subscribe statement, as subscribing to the route params is an asynchronous action, thus it is required to await for the response to be returned, before `id` is populated.

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.route.params.subscribe(params => { 
    this.id = +params['id'];
    console.log(this.id);
    this.loadData(this.id); // return number from url
  }); // get id and convert to number
}
```

Next, if you want to log the value of `employee`, you will need to subscribe to it before assigning the returned value to employee. Otherwise, you will only get the logged output of the observable as it wasn't returned.

```
loadData(id: number) {
  this.employeeService.getEmployee(this.id)
    .pipe(
      map(employees => employees.data)
    ).subscribe(res => {
      this.employee = res;
      console.log(this.employee);
    });
}
```

If you do not wish to subscribe to `getEmployee`, you will have to use the `async` pipe on your template html.